# this form (codeigniter) doesn't work

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I don't seem to be able to make a simple form work in codeigniter..

the following code:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
echo form_open('welcome/test_form');
echo form_button('button_name', 'click!');
echo form_close();
```

produces the following HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8888/index.php/welcome/test_form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<button name="button_name" type="button" >click!</button>
</form>
```

Yet when i click on the button nothing happens, the page stays the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: it is because you are using a button. makae it submit by form_submit() or add on onclick in form_button to do the submit in jQuery/ Javascript

Comment: <button type="submit">Submit</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating a submit button. You need to use something like this:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
echo form_open('welcome/test_form');
echo form_submit('button_name', 'click!');
echo form_close();
```

docs here:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

the `button` element is not the same as a `submit` button. It won't submit your form.

Comment: You're right. I've also 'discovered' you can still use form_button() and specify type='submit' in the properties.